# How to update specific rows SQL without another language?

Tags: mysql, sql

Im a CS student and having trouble understand this SQL question.. Iv been working on it below but still do not understand it completely..

Suppose you have a task table like this one. (The real table might have 
thousands of rows.)

```
mysql> select * from task; 
-------------------------------------------------
| id | name | state   | started           | pid | 
|------------------------------------------------
|  1 | sccl | ready   | 20120917 16:38:23 |   0 | 
|  2 | ela  | ready   | 20120917 16:38:31 |   0 | 
|  3 | ccpl | done    | 20120917 16:38:36 |   0 | 
|  4 | spl  | ready   | 20120917 16:38:39 |   0 | 
|  5 | uwec | pulling | 20120917 16:38:58 |   0 | 
|  6 | ut   | ready   | 20120917 16:39:03 |   0 | 
|  7 | van  | ready   | 20120917 16:41:32 |   0 | 
|  8 | art  | ready   | 20120917 16:59:03 |   0 | 
|  9 | bro  | ready   | 20120917 16:59:17 |   0 | 
-------------------------------------------------
```

We need to run a compute intensive process for each task that is in “ready” state.

The process should switch the state to “computing” when the computation starts (when the task is assigned) and then to “computed” when it finishes.

Each computation will take from 560 minutes.

Run (at most) 3 computation processes simultaneously until all ready 
tasks have been processed.

Write the SQL statements to manage the computation.

```
DECLARE @CCOUNT INT;
DECLARE @CAP INT;
DECLARE #SPACE INT;

SET @CCOUNT = COUNT(state) FROM task WHERE state = ‘computing’;
SET @CAP = 3;
SET @SPACE = @CAP - @CCOUNT

SELECT * FROM task WHERE state = “ready” limit @SPACE
UPDATE…(Update state to “computing”)
UPDATE…(Update state to “computing”)
```

**Problem**

I know I cant pass a variable to represent how many 'computing' processes there are without involving another language like Java or PHP.

I need to write SQL statements that basically outlines what it would look like without using other languages.

I was thinking to go above and beyond and first check if other process with the state 'computing' are running before we grab some tasks but how do I store them?

This might be a bit confusing but basically I need to answer this question with purely SQL statements.

If you can help that would be amazing!

Comment: DECLARE @C INT; SET @C = COUNT(state) FROM task where state = 'computing'.  should be a starting point.

Comment: Please tag properly.  This is `mysql`, not `sql server`.

Comment: @DaveBrown Ok im updated my answer above to as much as i can understand. How does it look? Also how do i update the tasks that were selected in the current processes?

Comment: @Eric done sorry!